# How do I specify a valid character property using Oniguruma regexes?

Tags: ruby, regex, oniguruma

I'm using the oniguruma gem to get unicode-aware regexes in ruby 1.8.  According to the syntax documentation, I should be able to use `\p{M}` or `\p{Mark}` to match code points with the Mark property.

However, when I do the following

```
ORegexp.new '\p{M}',
            :options => OPTION_MULTILINE | OPTION_SINGLELINE | OPTION_IGNORECASE | OPTION_EXTEND,
            :syntax => SYNTAX_JAVA, # so we can use character properties
            :encoding => ENCODING_UTF8
```

I get `ArgumentError: Oniguruma Error: invalid character property name {M}`.  I get the same error if I use `{Mark}`, or if I use one of the other syntaxes that support `\p`.

What am I doing wrong?  How do I specify a valid character property using Oniguruma regexes?

UPDATE - If I use one of the UTF16 encodings, the regex compiles; but since my strings are in UTF8 that doesn't help.  So my question becomes: how do I specify a valid character property using *UTF-8* Oniguruma regexes?

Comment: Is your source file encoded in UTF-8?

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
/\p{Mark}
```

I was reading on an old Ruby blog that using the forward slash would "try to find the value *as encoding in the string*"

http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/154384